# Best way to transfer database to new website without access to previous one

Tags: database, extract, web-hosting, data-transfer

I has old website, which I miss dashbored login info, so I didn't has access to its database

Now I implement new one, what the best way to extract previous data (mp3 files, articals, mp4 files) to use it in new one.

I hope there is a way to extract its not manually

Thanks

Comment: if you don't have access to the database, then how do you expect to get any data from it? Think about what you are asking, it's not logical. Can you get into a safe without the key (assuming you're not a criminal!)?

Comment: You should always store your credentials, such as usernames and passwords for important sites, securely in a password manager, then you can't forget them. If your old website is on a hosting platform, it's possible the hosting provider can help you regain access to it - maybe there is a password reset feature, or some security procedure you can go through with their helpdesk in order to prove your identity and regain access to your dashboard and your database. If you can't get to the database, then you can't copy any data from it.

Comment: Once you've regained access, you should be able to write or generate SQL scripts or a database backup file which you can then easily transfer to your new site.

Comment: The old website is like blog, it displays articala and lectures, so I don't need extract secure database, I need extract articals with titles and publish data

Comment: I agree important info should store it, but I was develop it by a company then I miss the company

Comment: what do you mean by "miss" the company? That's not a normal phrase. Do you mean that someone else made the website for you but then they didn't give you the password? Does that company not exist any more?

Comment: Yeah I mean the company is exist.

Comment: If the company exists, then why can't you contact them to get the relevant login information?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest in future all extraneous matter, images, mp3s etc. be held in a separate folder on your server, and hyperlinked to where they appear on a page.

That folder can be downloaded for safe-keeping.

.

In this case, I can only suggest that if the website is still up ( since you've simply lost the keys ), as an ordinary user you could download the whole website [ which wouldn't include the database ]  with something like wget or Httrack to your computer, and from that extract what items are possible to your computer [ filtering by extensions if need be ].

At the very least you should get an idea of which items were present, even if they don't download.

As for articles, either the website online, or the downloaded website should display them in a browser, and you could copy the text.

None of this applies if the website is no longer online;  but I wish you well whatever the outcome.